# Crear columna nueva condicionada a valores nulos de otras columnas del dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, numpy, null

necesito crear una columna condicionada a los valores que tienen otras columnas. Mi dataframe es el siguiente (PIB_Demanda):

```
  Tipo de dato    Agregados macro:Nivel1    Agregados macro:Nivel6   
1 No ajustados    Demanda nacional          NaN             
2 No ajustados    Demanda nacional          Gasto en consumo final
```

Lo que busco es crear una columna nueva con los valores de las columnas "Agregados macroeconómicos:Nivel1" y "Agregados macroeconómicos:Nivel6" en función de si tiene blancos o no.

En concreto escribo el siguiente código:

```
conditionlist = [(PIB_Demanda['Agregados macro:Nivel1'] != 'nan') & (PIB_Demanda['Agregados 
macro:Nivel6'] == 'nan'),
(PIB_Demanda['Agregados macro:Nivel6'] != 'nan')]
choicelist = [PIB_Demanda.columns[1], PIB_Demanda.columns[2]]
PIB_Demanda ['Agregados macroeconómicos'] = np.select(conditionlist, choicelist)
```

Dándome como resultado el siguiente dataframe con la columna nueva:

```
  Tipo de dato    Agregados macro:Nivel1    Agregados macro:Nivel6    Agregados macroeconómicos   
1 No ajustados    Demanda nacional          NaN                       Agregados macro:Nivel6
2 No ajustados    Demanda nacional          Gasto en consumo final    Agregados macro:Nivel6
```

Esto no es lo que busco, primero porque en la nueva columna me pinta el nombre de la columna, cuando lo que necesito es el valor que contiene la columna, y segundo porque en la primera línea me debería haber pintado la columna el Nivel1 no el Nivel6. Es decir, lo que busco sería el siguiente dataframe:

```
  Tipo de dato    Agregados macro:Nivel1    Agregados macro:Nivel6    Agregados macroeconómicos   
1 No ajustados    Demanda nacional          NaN                       Demanda nacional
2 No ajustados    Demanda nacional          Gasto en consumo final    Gasto en consumo final
```

He probado a poner un montón de sentencias distintas para seleccionar los NaA (is not null, is not None, != ' '), pero nada me funciona. ¿Podríais ayudarme? Muchas gracias Gracias

Comment: Buen día, ya hay múltiples preguntas similares, todas apuntando al mismo método, tal vez el escenario no es exactamente el mismo (Por eso no reporté la pregunta como duplicada) pero al leer las respuestas se puede inferir la solución a este escenario, deberías buscar en las preguntas ya hechas antes de hacer una publicación. De igual forma publiqué una respuesta para este escenario. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la observación @HeytalePazguato. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima ocasión. Además de ser nueva utilizando Python, también soy nueva en StacKoverflow y me lio con las normas. Perdonadme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es utilizando `fillna()`

Ejemplo con los datos que pusiste utilizando un archivo "sample.csv"

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['prueba'] = df['Agregados macro:Nivel6'].fillna(df['Agregados macro:Nivel1'])
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    Tipo de dato    Agregados macro:Nivel1  Agregados macro:Nivel6  prueba
0   No ajustados    Demanda nacional        NaN                     Demanda nacional
1   No ajustados    Demanda nacional        Gasto en consumo final  Gasto en consumo final
```